# Are custom named type's conversions functions or language construct

Tags: go, variables, type-conversion, declaration

I am unable to find any specific documentation for this feature (which I see in some code examples).

```
type Event string
type Num int

func main() {
    foo := Event("my event")
    bar := Num(45)
}
```

Is Go dynamically creating custom-named functions (conversion functions?) for each custom-named type?

Comment: `T(x)` is a [conversion expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions). `x := y` is an "ok way" to declare a variable, it's called the [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations).

Comment: Thank you. So, these "conversions" are not typical functions - they are language construct? I am surprised they are nowhere mentioned as a variable declaration method. Tutorials show only "var foo float32 = 2.7" but not "foo := float32(2.7)" that's why I am lost for a while.

Comment: Conversions have nothing to do with variable declarations. You may do `fmt.Println(Num(45))` - there is a conversion here and no variable declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is Go dynamically creating custom-named functions (conversion functions?)

No, it's a conversion expression defined by the language specs.

- `Event` is a [defined type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions), defined as `type Event string`
- `"my event"` is a string literal
- the syntax `<type>(<expression>)` is a [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions).

> An explicit conversion is an expression of the form `T(x)` where `T` is a type and `x` is an expression that can be converted to type `T`.

A literal is a constant expression (with just one operand).

> A constant value `x` can be converted to type `T` if `x` is representable by a value of `T`.

Is the string literal `"my event"` representable by an `Event` value? Yes, because `Event`'s underlying type is `string`.